# PHP loop within html table

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following html code:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How should I generate this using php loop?? Here the code I tried:

```
<?php
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
        echo "\t<td>";
        echo ($x);
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

But it is now what I need, how to set up 3 rows and with 12 items?? I know this is too simple for experts but too complicated for a newbie so looking for your help.

Thanks

Comment: note about the dupe: it might look like something different, but the principle is the same. chunk the array with your values. foreach chunk write a tr element and explode the values into it in td elements.

Comment: Thanks!  I will have a look at it and test!

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  I tried the solution you gave me and it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
    if ($x % 3 == 1)
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$x}</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You're missing `</tr>`.

Comment: </tr> is optional. Not required.

Comment: Working as well and very interesting finding! Thanks for sharing